# Using the ratio test to find which values of x a series converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I am trying to find for which values of x for which the sum of the series $\frac{x^n}{n}$, from n=1 to $\infty$, the series converges absolutely.

I am attempting to solve this using the ratio test:
$\frac{xn}{n+1}<1$ for the series to converge.

I rearrange this to give $$x<\frac{n+1}{n}$$  $$\Rightarrow  x<1+\frac{1}{n}$$

I then say as n can only be an integer greater than or equal to one, the maximum value the right hand side that the inequality can have is 2, therefore x must be less than 2 for the series to converge. I am not sure if this holds for negative values of x and if i am allowed to rearrange the ratio test this way.

Comment: What can you say about the special cases $x = \pm 1$?

Comment: I suppose you did notice that your summation is the Taylor expansion of -Log[1-x]. May be, what I wish and hope, this could be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

What about Cauchy-Haddamard's formula ($\;n-$ th root test...sort of)?

$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{|x|^n}n}=\frac{|x|}{\sqrt[n]n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}|x|$$

Thus, the series converges for $\;|x|<1\;$, and you can check easily that the series also converges at one of this interval's extreme points but diverges at the other one.